# How to change the file ACL in windows, if I only know the SID?

Tags: java, windows, acl, cacls, install4j

I want to change the ACL of a file and set "full permissions" to a special user.

I know the cacls-command `cacls . /e /t /p Everyone:f`

**But** this only works if the OS is english. For german systems, it must be
`cacls . /e /t /p Jeder:f`.

I know the [well-known SIDs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330) of the user "everyone" (S-1-1-0), but it seems as if I can't use them with cacls.

I tried `cacls . /e /t /p S-1-1-0:f`.

Is there a way to use windows command line tools for this jobs? I'm not allowed to bundle software or other commandline tools for this job with my software.

The solution has to be called from a Java-Process, but that should not be a problem.

Comment: cacls cannot work with SIDs.  If you're calling it from Java, why not convert the SID to a User in your program before invoking cacls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I am using a library from the vendor of my Setup creation tool.

**edit:**

Solution for problem:

The Setup-Creation Tool `Install4j` has a method `getUserLogin(String sid)` its returnvalue is something like: `WORKSTATION1\User1`

I used `cacls` to change the ACL.

Comment: How about telling us what the solution is so that this post has some value. Otherwise we might as well just close and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

This might be Windows version specific, but look at

```
 whoami /groups
```

and parse the result.  On Windows 7,  this

```
 whoami /groups | find "S-1-1-0"
```

looks like this for me

```
C:\>whoami /groups | find "S-1-1-0"
Everyone                                  Well-known group S-1-1-0
                     Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
```

There's a whole Win32 API for getting at this.  Here's a solution using that from C#

http://www.ms-news.net/f2438/setpermission-everyone-c-4997971.html