# Java - Access file with user authentication

Tags: java, authentication, file-access

I have a server where I work with a database and files using a java app.
When I start my app I give a report regarding file access to the server using:

```
public static boolean folderExists(String folderPath) {
    File folderToCheck = new File(folderPath);
    return folderToCheck.exists();
}
```

Every time I start my app (after a fresh restart of my computer)
I get a false response, even though the server is on.
The reason is because I must give an authentication as another user.
What I do is access the server through Windows 
where I am being asked for username/password,
and after that I get a true response regarding file access to the server.

Is there a way to **give the authentication username/password through Java**,
and not through Windows?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows 'native' Java IO (e.g. java.io.File) always inherits the security context of the user running the JVM process. For example, you could run the Java app as a Windows service with the correct credentials.

The JCIFS project implements [CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) (the Windows SMB file server protocol) and allows you to directly specify the username/password.

See the [API](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure, that there is no way to grant fileaccess by java, without a Windows-Call.

You can call `cacls file.log /e /t /p Everyone:f` but this will be language-dependent.

I had a similar problem: [How to change the file ACL in windows, if I only know the SID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389868/how-to-change-the-file-acl-in-windows-if-i-only-know-the-sid)

With Java7 there may be a way to do this.

Comment: Can I do it by calling a shell command? It's ok with me. I am using Windows. How would the command be?

Comment: I change the permission of a file bycalling *cacls* `cacls file.log /e /t /p Everyone:f`: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754/en But be aware, that the user with the login "Everyone", may have a different name on a localized windows. For a german translated windows, the call have to be `cacls file.log /e /t /p Jeder:f`