# how to delete, create and update a file in network drive using username and password in java

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

I am trying to delete a file on network (y drive) drive using below code

```java
import org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemOptions;
import org.apache.commons.vfs.UserAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.vfs.auth.StaticUserAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.vfs.VFS;
import org.apache.commons.vfs.FileObject;

public class DeleteLogFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filePath = "y:\\test\\test.log";

        String domain = "ABCDESDX";
        String userName = "abc";
        String password = "xyzl@jun2013";
        String remoteFilePath = filePath;

        try {

            UserAuthenticator auth = new StaticUserAuthenticator(domain, userName, password);
            FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();
            DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserAuthenticator(opts, auth);

            FileObject fo = VFS.getManager().resolveFile(remoteFilePath, opts);

            if (fo.exists()) {

                System.out.println("FILE IS THERE");
                if (fo.delete()) {
                    System.out.println("deleted");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

file is deleting by above program but this program are not using username and password because if I putting wrong credential then still file is deleting

PLEASE SUGGEST ON THIS or alternative way to achieve this requirement

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you should use CIFS :

[CIFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734845/java-access-file-with-user-authentication)

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599999/write-i-o-file-to-shared-network-drive-using-credentials)

Let me know if this is the right way, I just found two links but never tried this ;)

Comment: as i know cifs we use for windows shared drive ... in case of unix?